# control + click open new tab

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-router

I'm trying to include in my full application the option of open in a new tab if user do "control + click".

It's not possible to me do to it in every element so, I thought about do use  router events in app.component.

After some research it seems it's not possible to know how the navigation event was generated, is it correct?

Do you know another way to do it?

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
     console.log(event) //no generation info
  }
}
```

Comment: The NG router only applies to your website. You can't open a new window and have the same router instance in that newly opened window.

Comment: ctrl+click to new tab is standard browser behavior for clicking on a link. Every router link should have this functionality natively.